# Is there a way to do one-time pads(OTP) with Linux cryptsetup(dm-crypt)?

Tags: disk-encryption, cryptsetup, dm-crypt

It looks like losetup with cryptoloop did it and there was a dm-xor module for a very old kernel, but can't find anything modern. I'm wading through a ton of obsolete losetup documents.

Something like this:

`cryptsetup open --key-file /dev/disk/by-label/randomdatadisk --type plain --cipher xor /dev/disk/by-label/encrypteddisk decrypted`

There must be a way to do this, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might be thinking of one-time passwords. One-time pads for disk encryption would essentially take a write disk and a random disk. Data would be XORed with the random disk before writing and the after reading it would be XORed with the random disk again.

Comment: You can kind of build an xor disk with mdadm but I would not use this for crypto. Not to mention all that storage space to hold an entire disk worth of random data - what is the point when you can just leave that to a regular cipher?

Comment: The future proofing is the only reason. The XOR from mdadm isn't direct, it includes all kinds of headers and junk. Assuming a direct XOR I could manually XOR it back in the future even if mdadm standards change.

Comment: @Pedro apologies. I misread.